# Division of Two Variables in Twig file.

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following two variables in twig file.

```
{%set sanstha_target%}
    {%render 'FrontBundle:Datasheet:getCurrentTarget' with {'dealer':recent_entry.id,'month':recent_entry.year~recent_entry.month,'type':'3'}%}
{%endset%}

{%set sanstha_actual%}
    {%render 'FrontBundle:Datasheet:getTotal' with {'datasheet':recent_entry.datasheet,'dealer':recent_entry.id,'type':'3'}%}
{%endset%}
```

The when I am going to divide this getting this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class Twig_Markup could not be converted to int...
```

I need to get the percentage like this

```
{{ (sanstha_actual/sanstha_target)*100}}
```

Comment: As far as I know `{% render %}` creates subrequest to controller method. That being said, it **does not** return single value but `Response` instead (which `Twig` knows how to unwrap and inject into template).

Comment: What does those controller functions (`getCurrentTarget` and `getTotal`) return; a response or a rendered view html?

Comment: getCurrentTarget and getTotal returns a value as response. Is there any way to get this response as int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have to use two slashes, i.e.

```
{{ (sanstha_actual // sanstha_target) * 100 }}
```

as shown in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math):

> //: Divides two numbers and returns the floored integer result. {{ 20
>   // 7 }} is 2

Comment: These two variables are rendering from controller method , Error is Notice: Object of class Twig_Markup could not be converted to int